# KML file not showing anything on the google map

Tags: layers, kml

When i import this KML file: https://yadi.sk/d/G3DJywNAliflew

Nothing shows up on the map, just centering around Kazakhstan. This KML file has layer (like 2G cellular coverage map).

What i am doing wrong? Can i use this KML in a Yandex maps as well?

Comment: Works fine for me. The kml "calls" for the image which is within the "files" folder. Is this file within the same folder as your kml?

Comment: Yes, it is. Could you, please, throw an example, how you tested it and it worked?

Comment: I just double clicked on the .kml file and it opened, zoomed to Kazakhstan and the 2G cover map is shown over it. Nothing special. If anything, I'm using Google Earth Pro

Comment: Ah, i thought you were trying to open it using google maps. Is that KML/KMZ is intended for google maps / google earth only?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I completely missed the Yandex part. You are right, it doesn't work there, but I tried with a vector .kml and it worked fine. I would suggest opening the .kml in qgis, perform a vectorization (you can use gdal's "polygonize" from the toolbox - I did it and it worked) and the output vector will have an attribute table based on the digital numbers of the original raster. You can select the part of the layer that you wish (or all of it) and export it to new kml and upload it to Yandex

Comment: So, my current KMZ needs to be adopted for yandex maps?

Comment: Judging by the fact that in Yandex I was able to upload a vector .kml file, but not the raster one then yes, I would say it needs to be converted. Keep in mind, however, I'm no expert in Yandex maps.

Comment: Were you able to see the shape at Kazakhstan edges? Just installing Qgis now to convert my file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91285/discussion-between-kowalski-and-alexander-kim).